# Are Visual studio and VScodium softwares same?

Tags: programming, source-code, visual-studio-code, qt-creator, atom

I don't understand. Programmers says VS and VScodium. When i try to install VScodium, everything looks same as VS. Visual Studio (VS) community is freemium and the other part of enterprise software paid for enterprise users.

Are VS and VScodium same?

Answer (score 2):

From [the project website for VSCodium](https://vscodium.com):

> VSCodium is a community-driven, freely-licensed binary distribution of Microsoft’s editor VSCode
>
> Why Does This Exist
>
> Microsoft’s vscode source code is open source (MIT-licensed), but the product available for download (Visual Studio Code) is licensed under this not-FLOSS license and contains telemetry/tracking. According to this comment from a Visual Studio Code maintainer ...

So, in plain English, Microsoft's release of VS Code sends data back to Microsoft. VSCodium does not.

There are other differences, all of which can be found on the VSCodium project landing page

Comment: if i install snap VSCodium copy text from command line dont work at my `kUbuntue20.04` the VSCode from the repository dos not have this issue. maybe i need to install VSCodium differently